# Can we store password in without being hashing?

Tags: database, password

Actually I'm not against hashing but I'm sending user data from website A to website B for being same username and password. In such scenario when I extract password from website A it is already hashed and when I again use **wp_insert_user()** at website B for the username and password of website A, the password hashing function again executes and hashed password of website A will become password of website. Is there any solution suggestion for using same password and username on both website without using **CUSTOM_USER_TABLE** at wp-config file.
Example:

- Password(A): 'Test@123'    Stored Password(A) :
- PasswordHash("TEST@123") in database Password(B):
- PasswordHash("TEST@123") Stored Password(B) :
- PasswordHash(PasswordHash("TEST@123")) in database

Is there any solution for having same password on both website. Thanks

Comment: I don't think passwords is the right way here: in any case even if you did have the password on site A in clear how would you post it to site B to login? You could post a signed JWT token or something similar instead that site B can unpack into a valid login with an 'authenticate' or 'determine current user' filter, or use something like oAuth, or maybe even get site A to write a site B cookie via an iframe or similar trick, but I think that's getting harder to do with modern browsers.

Comment: @Rup Thanks for your interest. I've used custom endpoint api to send data. Now what I only need is any of these three:: #1. Extract password without hashing from A    
    #2. Decrypt password     #3. Store password at B without hashing at B

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet so I'll comment here:

You're not going to be able to decrypt wp passwords easily. They're salted and even if you keep entering the same password, the hashed password in the database is going to be different every time.  Your best bet is to do something like this on the site where you want to capture the password:

```
add_action('wp_authenticate','my_password_grabber');

function my_password_grabber () {
    $userName = $_POST['log'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];        
}
```

You can validate the user by doing:

```
if (is_email($userName)) {
    $user = wp_authenticate_email_password(NULL, $userName, $password);
} else {
    $user = wp_authenticate_username_password(NULL, $userName, $password);
}
```